# Unit testing XML Generation

Tags: c#, xml, unit-testing, nunit

What unit testing strategies do people recommend for testing xml is being generated correctly.

The my current tests seem abit primitive, something along the lines of:

```
[Test]
public void pseudo_test()
{
   XmlDocument myDOC = new XmlDocument();
   mydoc = _task.MyMethodToMakeXMLDoc();

   Assert.AreEqual(myDoc.OuterXML(),"big string of XML")
}
```

Answer (score 22):

First, as pretty much everyone is saying, validate the XML if there's a schema defined for it.  (If there's not, define one.)

But you can build tests that are a lot more granular than that by executing XPath queries against the document, e.g.:

```
string xml="Your xml string here" ;
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(xml);
path = "/doc/element1[@id='key1']/element2[. = 'value2']";
Assert.IsTrue(doc.SelectSingleNode(path) != null);
```

This lets you test not only whether or not your document is semantically valid, but whether or not the method producing it is populating it with the values that you expect.

Answer (score 7):

[Fluent Assertions](https://fluentassertions.com/) is an excellent library for expressing test assertions in a fluent, easy to read style. It works with all the major Unit Testing frameworks.

It also has some useful XML functionality (all taken from the examples [here](https://fluentassertions.com/xml/)), for example:

```
xElementA.Should().Be(xElementB);

xDocument.Should().HaveRoot("configuration");
xDocument.Should().HaveElement("settings");

xElement.Should().HaveAttribute("age", "36");
xElement.Should().HaveElement("address");

xAttribute.Should().HaveValue("Amsterdam");
```

Note that this works with LINQ-To-XML rather than the XmlDocument object specified in the original question but personally these days I find I'm using LINQ-To-XML as a first choice.

It is also quite easily extensible, should you want to add further XML assertions to fit your needs.

Answer (score 6):

Another possibility might be to use XmlReader and check for an error count > 0. Something like this:

```
    void CheckXml()
    {
        string _xmlFile = "this.xml";
        string _xsdFile = "schema.xsd"; 
        StringCollection _xmlErrors = new StringCollection();

        XmlReader reader = null;
        XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
        settings.ValidationEventHandler += new ValidationEventHandler(this.ValidationEventHandler);
        settings.ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema;
        settings.IgnoreComments = chkIgnoreComments.Checked;
        settings.IgnoreProcessingInstructions = chkIgnoreProcessingInstructions.Checked;
        settings.IgnoreWhitespace = chkIgnoreWhiteSpace.Checked;
        settings.Schemas.Add(null, XmlReader.Create(_xsdFile));
        reader = XmlReader.Create(_xmlFile, settings);
        while (reader.Read())
        {
        }
        reader.Close();
        Assert.AreEqual(_xmlErrors.Count,0);
    }    

    void ValidationEventHandler(object sender, ValidationEventArgs args)
    {
        _xmlErrors.Add("<" + args.Severity + "> " + args.Message);
    }
```

Comment: XMLUnit already will compare xml files and count the number of differences if you want...

Answer (score 4):

Validate against XML schema or DTD, also check key that nodes have the values you expect.

Comment: +1, and C#'s XmlSerialization could help with this.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a standard format that you expect the output to be, why not create an XML schema or DTD and validate against that. This won't depend on the data, so will be flexible. Also defining how the XML can be formed can be helpful when designing you system.

Answer (score 1):

Another reason to use a Schema to validate against is that while XML nodes are explicitly ordered, XML attributes are not.

So your string comparison of:

```
Assert.AreEqual(myDoc.OuterXML(),"big string of XML")
```

would fail if the attributes are in a different order, as could easily happen if one bit of XML was manually created and the other programatically.

Answer (score 1):

[This blog post](http://weblogs.asp.net/marianor/archive/2009/01/02/easy-way-to-compare-two-xmls-for-equality.aspx) by marianor gives a lightweight way to compare XElement structures, so I'm going to try that before tackling [XMLUnit](http://xmlunit.sourceforge.net/).

> The first thing to do is normalize the two XMLs...using Linq... After both elements were normalized, simply you can compare both strings.

The XML is normalized by sorting the element and attribute names.

Answer (score 0):

why not assume that some commercial xml parser is correct and validate your xml code against it? something like.

```
Assert.IsTrue(myDoc.Xml.ParseOK)
```

other than that and if you want to be thorough I'd say you would have to build a parser yourself and validate each rule the xml specification requires.

Answer (score 0):

Validate it against an XSD schema using XmlSchema class. Its found under System.XML i think.
Another option would be to write a serialization class (XMLSerializer) to deserialize your XML into an object. The gain will be that it will implicitly validate your structure and after that the values can be easily accessed for testing using the resulting object.

Comment: there is a better validation method using XMLUnit ...

Answer (score 0):

Verify the resulting document is well formed
Verify the resulting document is valid
Verify the resulting document is correct.

Presumably, you are crafting an XML document out of useful data, so you will want to ensure that you have the right coverage of inputs for your tests.  The most common problems I see are

- Incorrectly escaped elements
- Incorrectly escaped attributes
- Incorrectly escaped element names
- Incorrectly escaped attribute names

So if you haven't already done so, you would need to review the XML spec to see what's allowed in each place.

How much "checking" should happen in each test isn't immediately clear.  It will depend a lot on what a unit is in your problem space, I suppose.  It seems reasonable that each unit test is checking that one piece of data is correctly expressed in the XML.  In this case, I'm in agreement with Robert that a simple check that you find the right data at a single XPath location is best.

For larger automated tests, where you want to check the entire document, what I've found to be effective is to have an Expected results which is also a document, and walk through it node by node, using XPath expressions to find the corresponding node in the actual document, and then applying the correct comparison of the data encoded in the two nodes.

With this approach, you'll normally want to catch all failures at once, rather than aborting on first failure, so you may need to be tricksy about how you track where mismatches occurred.

With a bit more work, you can recognize certain element types as being excused from a test (like a time stamp), or to validate that they are pointers to equivalent nodes, or... whatever sort of custom verification you want.

Answer (score 0):

I plan on using this new [Approval Testing](http://approvaltests.sourceforge.net/) library to help with XML testing.

It looks to be perfect for the job, but read it first yourself as I don't have experience using it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a DTD to check for the validity of the generated xml.

To test for the correct content I would go for [XMLUnit](http://www.xmlunit.org).

Asserting xml using XMLUnit:

```
XMLUnit.setIgnoreWhitespace(true);
XMLUnit.setIgnoreDiffBetweenTextAndCDATA(true);

Diff diff = new Diff(expectedDocument, obtainedDocument);
XMLAssert.assertXMLIdentical("xml invalid", diff, true);
```

One thing you might come across is the fact that the generated xml might contain changing identifiers (id/uid attributes or alike). This can be solved by using a [DifferenceListener](http://www.xmlunit.org/api/java/master/org/custommonkey/xmlunit/DifferenceListener.html) when asserting the generated xml.

Example implementation of such DifferenceListener:

```
public class IgnoreVariableAttributesDifferenceListener implements DifferenceListener {

    private final List<String> IGNORE_ATTRS;
    private final boolean ignoreAttributeOrder;

    public IgnoreVariableAttributesDifferenceListener(List<String> attributesToIgnore, boolean ignoreAttributeOrder) {
        this.IGNORE_ATTRS = attributesToIgnore;
        this.ignoreAttributeOrder = ignoreAttributeOrder;
    }

    @Override
    public int differenceFound(Difference difference) {
        // for attribute value differences, check for ignored attributes
        if (difference.getId() == DifferenceConstants.ATTR_VALUE_ID) {
            if (IGNORE_ATTRS.contains(difference.getControlNodeDetail().getNode().getNodeName())) {
                return RETURN_IGNORE_DIFFERENCE_NODES_IDENTICAL;
            }
        }
        // attribute order mismatch (optionally ignored)
        else if (difference.getId() == DifferenceConstants.ATTR_SEQUENCE_ID && ignoreAttributeOrder) {
            return RETURN_IGNORE_DIFFERENCE_NODES_IDENTICAL;
        }
        // attribute missing / not expected
        else if (difference.getId() == DifferenceConstants.ATTR_NAME_NOT_FOUND_ID) {
            if (IGNORE_ATTRS.contains(difference.getTestNodeDetail().getValue())) {
                return RETURN_IGNORE_DIFFERENCE_NODES_IDENTICAL;
            }
        }

        return RETURN_ACCEPT_DIFFERENCE;
    }

    @Override
    public void skippedComparison(Node control, Node test) {
        // nothing to do
    }
}
```

using DifferenceListener:

```
    XMLUnit.setIgnoreWhitespace(true);
    XMLUnit.setIgnoreDiffBetweenTextAndCDATA(true);

    Diff diff = new Diff(expectedDocument, obtainedDocument);
    diff.overrideDifferenceListener(new IgnoreVariableAttributesDifferenceListener(Arrays.asList("id", "uid"), true));

    XMLAssert.assertXMLIdentical("xml invalid", diff, true);
```