# Good java library to compare xml files for unit testing?

Tags: java, xml, unit-testing

I am looking for a good java library to compare xml files in unit tests. Currenly we are using a simple string compare, but this requires that the xml file is printed the same way (currenly on 1 line).

I have found the following on the net: http://xmlunit.sourceforge.net/. But i looks old (latest version from  September 2009). Does somebody knows a more recent library or is this still the one to use?

Thanks

Comment: I've used xmlunit and it still works :)

Comment: Has XML changed since 2009? Why does xmlunit need to be updated?

Comment: Duplicate: see my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30646875/1183010)

Comment: XMLUnit is the answer. FYI they have a 2.0 now.

Answer (score 3):

[xml-matchers](http://code.google.com/p/xml-matchers/) is what you're looking for. The library seems to be actively supported:

```
assertThat(the(xml), isEquivalentTo(the(xml2)));
```

Also, try [jcabi-matchers](http://matchers.jcabi.com):

```
assertThat(XhtmlMatchers.the(xml), XhtmlMatchers.hasXPath("/html/body"))
```