# Most convenient way to unit test Xml/XElement result

Tags: c#, xml, unit-testing

I have some codes heavily uses `XElement` class to build segments of Xml, for example code looks like

```
        XNamespace ns = "ns";
        XElement myXml = new XElement(
            ns + "filter",
            new XElement(
                ns + "and",
                new XElement(
                    ns + "equals",
                    new XAttribute("name", "uid"),
                    new XElement(ns + "value", "some text"))));
```

It eventually spits out some Xml code equivalent to

```
        <ns:filter>
            <ns:and>
                <ns:equals name="uid">
                    <ns:value>some text</ns:value>
                </ns:equals>
            </ns:and>
        </ns:filter>
```

Now I need to unit test the logic go going through xpath, getting attributes and so on. I can always write my Linq-Xml to check the data, but it is very tedious since I need to unit test quite lot of similar codes.

I looked into `fluent assertions`, it is very close, but it does not seem to be able to validate nested element's value.

Any one has some good recommendation?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/503784/unit-testing-xml-generation I would go the XPath on the document way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call `XElement.DeepEquals(actual, expected)`.
However, you won't get useful failure messages.

You could also simply assert that their `ToString()`s are equal, and use your assertion framework's string differ.

Comment: I will accept this as a answer. But with my testing, I can see it has some weird behaviours, for example, once I have some value in my element coming from encryption by using RSA, the comparison fails.