# XMLSerializer producing different results on TeamCity

Tags: c#, unit-testing, teamcity, xml-namespaces, xmlserializer

We have added a legacy solution to TeamCity. One of the unit tests is now failing, despite the fact that it pass locally.

The unit test checks that the actual output string from an XmlSerializer is as expected.

```
string expectedXmlText = File.ReadAllText("TestFile.xml");
objectToSerialize = ...;

string actual = UtilsClass.SerializeObject(objectToSerialize);

Assert.That(xmlText, Is.EqualTo(expectedXmlText));
```

In TeamCity it fails with the following message:

```
Test(s) failed.   String lengths are both 476. Strings differ at index 59.
  Expected: "..."utf-16"?>\r\n<Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XM..."
  But was:  "..."utf-16"?>\r\n<Envelope xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XM..."
```

Note that the namespaces differ, one starts with **xsi** and one starts with **xsd**.

Now I realise that the XML is valid in both cases adn represents the same thing. I also realise that you shouldn't write code that relies on the order of namespaces in the XML.

**Questions**

1. What is the correct way to test the output of an XMLSerializer, is
   it wrong to check the output text?
2. Why would the XMLSerializer return the namespaces in a different order?

Answer (score 1):

2.

From [Inconsistent Namespace Order using XmlSerializer on x86/x64](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/cd01365d-f324-4682-a46d-eeb80575e31c/inconsistent-namespace-order-using-xmlserializer-on-x86x64?forum=csharpgeneral)

> The namespace collection is just a dictionary internally.  The order in which it returns values is undefined and can, theoretically, change each time you call it.  There is no rhyme or reason to dictionary ordering.  If you need consistent ordering then you have to switch to SortedDictionary and friends.
>
> More specifically XmlSerializerNamespaces uses a Hashtable internally which calculates where to place an item based upon what is already in the dictionary and the hashcode.  Hashtable actually rebuilds the dictionary periodically based upon how many collisions are occurring on insert.  This is documented in the MSDN information for the type.
>
> The takeaway is that there is no guarantees about ordering for dictionaries even for the same instance because the dictionary (or hashtable in this case) can reorder items to improve performance.  Generally we'd expect to see consistent behavior for a single instance and even across machines but there are no guarantees.

Answer (score 1):

Some people actually recommend to avoid using the `string` object an use the actual XML object from deserialization (whether it is an `XDocument` from LINQ-to-XML or an `XmlDocument` from the `System.Xml` core library).

There is another question presenting features from Fluent Assertions that shows some examples as well : [Unit testing XML Generation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503784/unit-testing-xml-generation)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with test_xml nampespaces (XSD and XSI) position not matching with control_xml namespaces in unit test

The solution was [XMLUnit.NET 2.x](https://github.com/xmlunit/xmlunit.net), it compares XMLs as XML object and not as String

https://github.com/xmlunit/xmlunit.net

Using Fluent API :

```
string String_Actual = serializadorAbstract.AsString;
string String_Expected = File.ReadAllText(@"ExpectedOutput\Alumnos.xml");

ISource control = Input.FromString(String_Expected).Build();
ISource test = Input.FromString(String_Actual).Build();

Diff differences = DiffBuilder.Compare(control).WithTest(test).Build();
Assert.IsFalse(differences.HasDifferences());
```